# any types in tables/table-like sets in nim

Tags: dictionary, nim-lang

How do i make it so tables can have any types for keys and values in Nim? For example, the following code doesn't work:

`{"a": "string", "b": 4}`

It says it expects (string, string) but got (string, int), meaning the type was determined from the first tuple. Since the any type in generics aren't allowed, how do I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following approach (taken from json module):

```
import hashes, tables

type MyTypeKinds = enum
    MNil, MInt, MString

type MyGenericType = object
  case kind*: MyTypeKinds

  of MString:
    str*: string

  of MInt:
    num*: BiggestInt

  of MNil:
    nil

proc hash(mg: MyGenericType): Hash =
  case mg.kind:
  of MString:
    result = hash(mg.str)
  of MInt:
    result = hash(mg.num)
  of MNil:
    result = hash(0)

proc `==`(a: MyGenericType, b: MyGenericType): bool =
  if a.kind != b.kind:
    return false
  case a.kind:
  of MString:
    return a.str == b.str
  of MInt:
    return a.num == b.num
  of MNil:
    return true

var genericTable = initTable[MyGenericType, MyGenericType]()

var key, val: MyGenericType

key.kind = MString
key.str = "a"

val.kind = MInt
val.num = 4

genericTable[key] = val

echo genericTable[key].num
```

For better readability you may want to implement something like json's [% operator](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/58080525a1dcad23de6ad0cf9ca6988f103de350/lib/pure/json.nim#L308).

This way you still cannot use any type but only a set of predefined ones, but that's all right since tables require types to have a hash proc.

**EDIT**: Made the code to compile successfully by adding a comparison proc and fixing typos

Answer (score 0):

```
#it is already in language core  : 
var Python_like_dic: openArray[(string, string)] = {"a": "string", "b": 4}


#iterations : 
for i in Python_like_dic : 
    echo i[0] , " = " , i[1]
```